# How to find number of http(s) connections (TCP) opened by my node JS micro-service (using axios KeepAlive for http) config, in GKE k8s environment?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, networking, tcp, netstat

**Problem Description/Context**

I have a nodeJS-based application using [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios/v/0.21.4#creating-an-instance) to make HTTP requests (Outbound REST API calls) against a web service (say https://any.example.restapis.com). And these HTTP requests occasionally used to take > 1-minute latency. After some debugging - when we tried httpsAgent property to keep the HTTP connections live (persistent) it did the trick and now the APIs are taking < 1 second and the application is working OK. Basically, my understanding is with this property the TCP connections used by the HTTP calls are persistent now and the httpsAgent is opening multiple socket connections against the web service (i.e; it's keeping the connections alive based on default configs and opening multiple TCP connections based on the load as required - basically maintaining a pool of connections)

```
httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
```

**Question**

We are not yet sending the full traffic 100% to the micro-service (just 1%). So I would like to understand in detail what is happening underneath to make sure the fix is indeed complete and my micro-service will scale to full traffic.

So, can anyone please let me know after SSH into the pod's container how I can check if my node JS application is indeed making **number of TCP (socket) connections** against the web service rather than just using **single TCP connection but keeping it alive** (I tried to use netstat -atp command like below - however I'm not able to make the connection). So, it will great if anyone help me with how to check **the number of TCP connections** made by my micro-service.

```
// example cmd -
// Looking at cmds like netstat, lsof as they may (hoping!) give me details that I want!  
netstat -atp | grep <my process ID>
```

Comment: can you run tcpdump on the pod? If so, I have a quick and dirty solution

Comment: Hi @Yarin_007 - A quick check looks like I can't run tcpdump on the container. Having said that I can update container to get the tcpdump in test environments and see what's happening if not production. Can you please share your thoughts/trick as one of the answers to the question? I will go through in detail and give it a try and update you. Thank you for taking time and responding. Appreciate your time! Regards.

Comment: we're gonna count the number of TCP SYN packets (there's exactly one at the start of every new tcp session that has the syn flag and not the ack flag, sent by the session initiator). `sudo tcpdump 'tcp[13] & 2 != 1 and tcp[13] & 16 = 0' --count`. then hit ctrl +C (or specify a timeout/max count in the tcpdump command.) and the packet count is the number of sessions created

Comment: Thank you @Yarin_007 - I will go through tcpdump tool to understand about the tool high level and try your approach. I will try the approach from my local MAC first by bring the micro-service up as I just want to know how the node js working with axios https.agent's keepalive config and then think about how to do it in k8s. Regards.

Comment: @Yarin_007 - just FYI. ended up running service under lot of load and simply watched the TCP connections for the IP addresses I was looking for - I did see multiple TCP connections while serving the load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the code is working and indeed opening multiple TCP connections with axios config https Agent with keepAlive.

The way I tested is:

1. Ran the service under a lot of load
2. used nslookup to find the IP address of the domain
3. And ran the netstat command in the pod's container like below - with **watch**

> watch 'kubectl exec -it -n my-namespace my-pod  -c pod-container  -- netstat
> -atlpn | grep "18/node (processID)" | grep "IP address"'